# Trying to toggle on/off numerous images based on varying conditions in C#/Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

thanks in advance for your help. I'm a hobbyist playing around with building an incremental clicker to learn various coding techniques and am trying to find a way to streamline a portion of my script. I'm going to have 80-100 different clickable images and I'd like the image to change color/turn on and off when it can/it can't be clicked to show a user when it can be interacted with. The conditions for when each can be clicked are different for every image. So far I've tried SetActive() and setting fillAmount to 0 or 1 however it's resulting in long and mostly repetitive code. Below is how I've tried both ways, could anyone recommend a way to streamline this so I don't have to write 4 lines of code for every clickable object? I've tried writing a quick program however I keep getting stuck with the conditions being different for every image.

```
    if ((data.food >= data.hutClickFoodConsumption) && (data.energy >= data.hutClickEnergyConsumption))
        hutClickYes.SetActive(true);
    else
        hutClickYes.SetActive(false);

    if ((data.food >= data.townPlannersClickFoodConsumption) && (data.energy >= data.townPlannersClickEnergyConsumption))
        townPlannersClickYes.fillAmount = 1;
    else
        townPlannersClickYes.fillAmount = 0;

    if ((data.food >= data.hiRiseClickFoodConsumption) && (data.energy >= data.hiRiseClickEnergyConsumption))
        hiRiseClickYes.fillAmount = 1;
    else
        hiRiseClickYes.fillAmount = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a large number of items, I generally like to store as much information as sensible within each item. And then I'll store those items in a collection. Because of the lack of `Dictionary<K, V>` serialisation in Unity, it's usually a `List<T>` so we can use the Inspector.

An example of that for your case might look something like this:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class ItemData
{
    public string Name;
    public float FoodConsumption;
    public float EnerguConsumption;
    public GameObject ItemObject; // (see notes)
    // add any extra item data here ...
}


public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<ItemData> _allItems;
    // Include your 'data' field or property here as well.
     
    public void Setup ( )
    {
        foreach ( var i in _allItems )
            i.ItemObject.SetActive ( 
                ( data.food >= i.FoodConsumption ) && 
                ( data.energy >= i.EnerguConsumption ) );
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can reduce the amount of code from hundreds of lines, to half a dozen. Also, the type of the referenced object could be a `GameObject` (as shown), or an `Image` if you're using the uGUI (think Canvas), or another referenced object to suit your needs.

The result of the above code then looks like this:
[image]

Obviously, this only works if all of the conditions can be boiled down to the boolean check in the example. But, it IS possible to add further data to extend the type checking. A quick example would be adding boolean values to the item data, indicating what fields need to be checked, and/or whether a value need to be less then, equal or greater than.

Comment: Thank you for offering to help! In your image above, where do the values (5,6,7,9) for Food and Energy consumption come from within your proposed code? I think where I'm getting stuck on this is that Food, Energy (and there two other consumption values in my code as well) is different for every item. That's why I've broken it down as "hutClickFoodConsumption" and "townPlannerClickFoodConsumption". I may be massively overthinking this but I do think you're approach is generally what I was imagining. It is a boolean check for every item which hopefully makes it easier.

Comment: @Yurconale the (5,6,7,9) values were just random values I added to demonstrate how you could enter the data for your items, through the Inspector. That way, you'd be able to add as many items as you wanted, and store the data. The next step would likely be to store the data as a ScriptableObject, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Understood. How do I connect the variables from my main script to this one? I've played around a bit and am getting the error "The name 'data' does not exist in the current context". Is this is a second script or did I misunderstand and this can live within the main one?

Comment: Quick edit, I got it to work without errors by placing the ItemData class in one script and then the rest in the primary script. I'm now seeing "All Items" in the inspector however it's not showing anything inside of it other than "Size".  How did your code pull in the distinct items "Hut" and "Town Planners" with the editable information below it?

Comment: @Yurconale at a stab, I reckon you've removed your `data` reference from the script. To be fair, I didn't include it in my example script. So, from your previous code (which I can't see), where you defined and assigned `data`, copy that code across to your new script.

Comment: @Yurconale did you include the `[Serializable]` attribute to the `ItemData` class? And are all the items in the class fields, as opposed to properties (i.e. {get;set;}) ?